# Can not get Bootstrap JS to work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get the Bootstrap JS to work. I am using the CDN, below is my `<head>` Hopefully one of you can spot my issue.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.`enter code here`jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head
```

Comment: Unrelated kind of* This part is not quite right: <script src="https://code.`enter code here`jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: jquery first before bootstrap. bootstrap js need jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap js has hard dependency on JQuery, you have to swap order of the two script tags in your head.

Also consider to move script tags before end of body tags not to block dom rendering.

Comment: I moved it and it worked, never made a template before so good to know the order of those two matter. I will move them yes, just starting a fresh template so slapped them there for now.

Comment: Btw, lots of scripts depends on jQuery to work, so it would be more of convention to put jQuery the first script tag, as browser loads scripts top to bottom in your template ;)